# Force ObservableCollection<T> collection to get a specific Type

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have this generic method in my base class:

```
protected void Show<T>(ObservableCollection<T> collection)
{
    StatusText = Resource.loadingData;
    if (collection is ObservableCollection<Language>)
    {
        collection = DBService.GetLanguages();
    }
    StatusText = string.Empty;
}
```

If the collection's type is Language, I want to force the collection to reference the DBService.GetLanguages()'s return `ObservableCollection<Language>`.

But the compiler says:

> A implicit conversion of "System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<DataModel.Language>" in "System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>" is not possible.

Comment: I think you mean `collection is ObservableCollection<Language>`, you'll also need to pass the collection in  using the `ref` parameter. Otherwise the value won't be saved.

Comment: see about [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hey Ned Stoyanov and okrumnow, thanks for your answers! I have modifed my if condition into if (collection is ObservableCollection<Language>). If (T is Language) doesn't work... Nevertheless, if I'm in the if statement I know that the collection can point or hold other ObservableCollections<Language>, why can't I compile it?

Comment: you can't compile it because compiler don't know what type is `T`, for solution you can cast to `ObservableCollection<T>` like `collection = DBService.GetLanguages() as ObservableCollection<T>;`

Comment: Thank you very much Grundy!!!! But one last question for my understanding: why doesn't the compiler allow this code: if (T is Language) or if(typeof(T) is Language)

Comment: also for comparing type you can use `typeof(T) == typeof(Language)`

Comment: Grundy, you make my day - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're doing something with `collection` inside this method (probably showing the members), but it's definitely no good idea to reassign collection inside the `Show` method. Check for type `Language` outside of the method and pass the correct collection to show.

BTW: you need to check `T` for type language, not the collection.